# Wordpress Page-Navi custom page error 404

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I installed Page-Navi plugin on my site.

I add new custom page with page navi.

mysite/page/1/ working 
mysite/page/2/ working 
mysite/page/3/ 404 not found 
....

```php
  $temp = $wp_query;
  $wp_query= null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query('post_type=post&showposts=4&paged='.$paged); 
      $count=1; 
     if (have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    // content
     endwhile;
    wp_pagenavi(); 
    wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with the following:

```
global $wp_query;

if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $paged = 1;
} 

$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type'      => 'post',
     'posts_per_page' => 4,
     'paged'          => $paged,
) ); 

$count=1; 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // content
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi(); 

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i still get this error 404 on page 3 and page 4.